# Trying to skip a column in a foreach statement C#

Tags: c#, foreach, multiple-columns, create-table

I have an inventory management program I am working on.  The way the Database and Table system is set up, is each category is a different table.  This is necessary as each category (ie. Shoes, Phones, Laptops) has different fields to uniquely identify each product.  So, I create a table and then add the user named columns through a foreach statement.  The problem I have is it wants to add the ID column when it already exists.  I tried Adding an If statement nested in the foreach, but it just keeps breaking the foreach loop. I just haven't figured out a way for it to skip the ID column and continue through each of the columns to add.

Here is the function code:

```
private void btnCreateCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> FieldNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in lstFieldNames.Items)
    {
        FieldNames.Add(lstFieldNames.Items.ToString());
    }

    DataTable NewCategory = new DataTable();
    NewCategory = CreateTable(FieldNames);
    dgPreviewAdd.DataSource = NewCategory;

    using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(
       Helper.cnnVal("InventoryManager")))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", Connection))
        {
            command.CommandText = "Create Table tbl" + 
                NewCategory.TableName.ToString() + "(ID int)";

            Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();

            foreach (DataColumn newColumn in NewCategory.Columns)
            {
                 If( newColumn.ColumnName("ID")
                  {
                  }
                  Else
                  {
                SqlParameter colparam = new SqlParameter();
                colparam.ParameterName = "@ColumnName";
                colparam.Value = newColumn.ColumnName.ToString();

                SqlParameter tblParam = new SqlParameter();
                tblParam.ParameterName = "@TableName";
                tblParam.Value = "tbl" + NewCategory.TableName.ToString();

                command.Parameters.Add(colparam);
                command.Parameters.Add(tblParam);
                command.CommandText = "dbo.AddCategoryColumns";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Connection.Close();
                }
            }

            LoadCategory catTableLoad = new LoadCategory();
            DataTable catTable = new DataTable();
            catTable = catTableLoad.getCategoryTable();

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@CategoryName";
            param.Value = NewCategory.TableName.ToString();

            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
            param2.ParameterName = "@IdNumber";
            param2.Value = catTable.Rows.Count + 1;

            command.Parameters.Add(param);
            command.Parameters.Add(param2);

            command.CommandText = "dbo.AddCategory";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point out the code which skips the ID column?

Comment: Sorry, must have been lost in the copy.  I added in the if else statement.

Comment: You could check in the stored procedure whether that column really already exists, and skip the addition if it does

Comment: For a completely different approach, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either of these:

```
foreach (DataColumn newColumn in NewCategory.Columns)
{
    if (newColumn.ColumnName == "ID") continue;

    //Rest of logic goes here
}
```

Or exclude from  the loop completely:

```
foreach (DataColumn newColumn in NewCategory.Columns.Where( c => c.ColumnName != "ID" ))
{

    //Rest of logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use distinct to group the category

do not forget to add using System.Linq;

```
private void btnCreateCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> FieldNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in lstFieldNames.Items)
        {
            FieldNames.Add(lstFieldNames.Items.ToString());
        }

        var grpfieldNames = FieldNames.Distinct();

        DataTable NewCategory = new DataTable();

        NewCategory = CreateTable(grpfieldNames);

        dgPreviewAdd.DataSource = NewCategory;

        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(
           Helper.cnnVal("InventoryManager")))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", Connection))
            {
                command.CommandText = "Create Table tbl" +
                    NewCategory.TableName.ToString() + "(ID int)";

                Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Connection.Close();

                foreach (DataColumn newColumn in NewCategory.Columns)
                {
                    If(newColumn.ColumnName("ID")
                      {
                    }
                    Else
                      {
                        SqlParameter colparam = new SqlParameter();
                        colparam.ParameterName = "@ColumnName";
                        colparam.Value = newColumn.ColumnName.ToString();

                        SqlParameter tblParam = new SqlParameter();
                        tblParam.ParameterName = "@TableName";
                        tblParam.Value = "tbl" + NewCategory.TableName.ToString();

                        command.Parameters.Add(colparam);
                        command.Parameters.Add(tblParam);
                        command.CommandText = "dbo.AddCategoryColumns";
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        Connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Connection.Close();
                    }
                }

                LoadCategory catTableLoad = new LoadCategory();
                DataTable catTable = new DataTable();
                catTable = catTableLoad.getCategoryTable();

                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@CategoryName";
                param.Value = NewCategory.TableName.ToString();

                SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
                param2.ParameterName = "@IdNumber";
                param2.Value = catTable.Rows.Count + 1;

                command.Parameters.Add(param);
                command.Parameters.Add(param2);

                command.CommandText = "dbo.AddCategory";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this even compile? `newColumn.ColumnName("ID")` misses closing `)` as well as doesn't seem like a proper syntax given `ColumnName` is a property.